# Issue with automatic UI updates in Apollo: `updateQuery` not working properly with `subscribeToMore`

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollostack, react-apollo

I'm using **GraphQL subscriptions** for my chat application, but I have an issue with the UI updates.

Here are the query and the mutation I'm using:

```
const createMessage = gql`
    mutation createMessage($text: String!, $sentById: ID!) {
        createMessage(text: $text, sentById: $sentById) {
            id
            text
        }
    }
`

const allMessages = gql`
    query allMessages {
        allMessages {
            id
            text
            createdAt
            sentBy {
                name
                location {
                    latitude
                    longitude
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Then, when exporting, I'm wrapping my `Chat` component like so:

```
export default graphql(createMessage, {name : 'createMessageMutation'})(
  graphql(allMessages, {name: 'allMessagesQuery'})(Chat)
)
```

I'm subscribing to the `allMessagesQuery` in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {

  // Subscribe to `CREATED`-mutations
  this.createMessageSubscription = this.props.allMessagesQuery.subscribeToMore({
    document: gql`
        subscription {
            Message(filter: {
                mutation_in: [CREATED]
            }) {
                node {
                    id
                    text
                    createdAt
                    sentBy {
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    updateQuery: (previousState, {subscriptionData}) => {
      console.log('Chat - received subscription: ', previousState, subscriptionData)
      const newMessage = subscriptionData.data.Message.node
      const messages = previousState.allMessages.concat([newMessage])
      console.log('Chat - new messages: ', messages.length, messages) // prints the correct array with the new message!!
      return {
        allMessages: messages
      }
    },
    onError: (err) => console.error(err),
  })

}
```

After I sent the message through the chat, the subscription is triggered successfully and I see the two logging statements that also contain the expected data. So the contents of `messages` are definitely correct within `updateQuery`!

However, the UI doesn't update automatically, in fact, all the previously displayed messages disappear.

My `render` method looks as follows:

```
render() {
  console.log('Chat - render: ', this.props.allMessagesQuery)
  return (
    <div className='Chat'>
      <ChatMessages
        messages={this.props.allMessagesQuery.allMessages || []}
      />
      <ChatInput
        message={this.state.message}
        onTextInput={(message) => this.setState({message})}
        onResetText={() => this.setState({message: ''})}
        onSend={this._onSend}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The logging statement in `render` shows that initially, `this.props.allMessagesQuery` has the array `allMessages`, so everything works after the initial loading.

**After the subscription is received, `allMessages` disappears from `this.props.allMessagesQuery`** which is why an empty array is given to `ChatMessages` and nothing is rendered.

**Before subscription is triggered** ✅

[image]

**After subscription is triggered** ❌

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after digging through the docs one more time, it was a mistake on my end!

This part from the [Apollo docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries) helped me solve the issue:

> Remember: You'll need to ensure that you select IDs in every query where you need the results to be normalized.

So, adding the `id` fields to the returned payload of my queries and subscriptions actually helped.

```
const allMessages = gql`
    query allMessages {
        allMessages {
            id
            text
            createdAt
            sentBy {
                id
                name
                location {
                    id
                    latitude
                    longitude
                }
            }
        }
    }
`

subscription {
    Message(filter: {
        mutation_in: [CREATED]
    }) {
         node {
            id
            text
            createdAt
            sentBy {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your update Query the previousState is the allMessages query that is saved in the react apollo store.

To update the store you have to make a deep copy or use some helper e.g. [reacts immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). The apollo developers page gives some information about how to update the store correctly [update Query](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries).

In your case it could look like this

```js
...
updateQuery: (previousState, { subscriptionData }) => {
  const newMessage = subscriptionData.data.Message.node;
  return update(previousState, {
    allMessages: { $push: [newMessage] },
  });
}
...
```