# ApolloClient: UI (ROOT_QUERY) not updating after subscription delete

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

apollo-client: 2.6.3
react-apollo: 2.2.1

So, I have a subscription that is fired upon an item delete request but does not update the UI after the subscription has taken place.

My subscription code is as follows:

```html
              <DeleteItem 
                id={item.id}
                urlReferer={urlReferer}
                subscribeToDeleteItems={() =>
                  subscribeToMore({
                    document: DELETE_ITEM_SUBSCRIPTION,
                    variables: {},
                    updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
                      if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
                      
                      const deletedItem = subscriptionData.data.itemDeleted;
                      let newItemList;
                      console.log("prev = ", prev);
              
                      if (isDuplicateItem(deletedItem.id, prev.me.items)) {
                        newItemList = prev.me.items.filter((item) => {
                          return deletedItem.id !== item.id;
                        });
                        console.log("new item list = ", newItemList);
                      } else {
                        return prev;
                      }

                      return Object.assign({}, prev, {
                        ROOT_QUERY: {
                          me: {
                            items: [newItemList]
                          }
                        }
                      }); 
                    }
                  })
                }
              >Delete This Item</DeleteItem>
```

and the generated output looks as follows:

[image]

ROOT_Query store:

[image]

What am I overlooking here and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this by changing the parent query's fetchPolicy to "cache-and-network" and ensuring that IDs were present in every query where results need to be normalised, as mentioned here: [Issue with automatic UI updates in Apollo: `updateQuery` not working properly with `subscribeToMore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492943/issue-with-automatic-ui-updates-in-apollo-updatequery-not-working-properly-wi)